# get data in group outlook with R

Tags: r, database, outlook

```
library(RDCOMClient)

folderName = "Groupes"

## create outlook object
OutApp <- COMCreate("Outlook.Application")
outlookNameSpace = OutApp$GetNameSpace("MAPI")

folder <- outlookNameSpace$Folders(1)$Folders(folderName)
```

Error :

```
<checkErrorInfo> 8002000E 
No support for InterfaceSupportsErrorInfo
checkErrorInfo -2147352562
Error: Nombre de paramètres non valide.
```

I would like get information content group mail in outlook by RDCOMClient.

Thanks,

Comment: That error means your parameter names aren't valid right? after which line do you get the error? Is there a way to manually check your parameters?

Comment: Thanks for your question. The goal is to get message content in email groupes in outlook by R package RDCOMClient. You can see in this link : https://www.google.com/search?q=outlook&rlz=1C1GCEB_enFR826FR826&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwijur-Q45HgAhUnx4UKHR7LDrEQ_AUIECgD&biw=1280&bih=610#imgrc=JDoub-U_Y6aNzM:

Comment: Your answer doesn't exactly address any of my questions :P Are you able to manually check that your parameters are correct? Or, is there documentation specifying what a 'valid' parameter is?

Comment: That link you added is just a link to the output from googling 'Outlook'...